# Constant with all items of an enum in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to have a constant set of all items of an enumerated type in Delphi?

```
type
    TItems = (
      iOne,
      iTwo,
      iThree
    );

    TItemsSet = set of TItems;

const
    SOMEITEMS: TItemsSet = [iTwo, iThree];


    ALLITEMS: TItemsSet = ?????
```

I would like ALLITEMS to always hold all members of TItems. And I would prefer to have this as constant.

**Edited:**
And what, if my enum looks like this:

```
TItems = (
  iOne = 1,
  iTwo = 2,
  iThree = 5
);
```

Comment: `[Low(TItems)..High(TItems)]`?

Comment: @hvd Obviously.. sorry, I missed that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(From the comments)

`[Low(T)..High(T)]` works for any type `T` that is small enough to be used as a set, to include all items that can be included in the set.

As noted in the comments, this is enough for the enumeration in the question, but in general, may include constants that aren't defined as part of the enumeration.

Comment: Is Delphi smart enough to handle this situation too: `TItems = (iOne = 1, iTwo = 2, iThree = 5);` ?

Comment: @AloisHeimer Now tested: `set of TItems` would have room for `iOne`, `iTwo`, `TItems(3)`, `TItems(4)` and `iThree`. `[Low(TItems)..High(TItems)]` would include all five of those, not only those that have names.